# How can I use a React hook in mapping without infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use a hook inside a function within a mapping that returns data based on the input. Currently this produces an infinite loop of logs in the console and I'm not sure how to solve this.

Please assume all use are hooks getting data, sorry I can't go into much detail without it becoming complicated. Please see code below:

```
export const ClaimForm = () => {

    const [accountLocksArray, setAccountLocksArray] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const accountLocks: Array<string> = useGetLocks()

    useEffect(() => {
        setAccountLocksArray(accountLocks);
      }, [accountLocks])

    const LockDisplay = ({ lock }: { lock: string }) => {

        const { lockExpiryTime, underlyingBalance } = useGetLockData(lock)

        console.log(lockExpiryTime, underlyingBalance)
    }

    return(                    
     { accountLocksArray.map((lock) => (
        <LockDisplay key={lock} lock={lock} />
     ))}
}
```

Please advise how to avoid infinite loops of hooks used in .map functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: defining a component inside a component is a bad idea, move it outside

Comment: wow, just doing this made it work! Why does this cause the problem?